# Missing edges when using add_edges_from with networkx- python

Tags: python, networkx

I have a `dict` with the edges in two tuples format and their values I want to add to a networkx `graph`.

`mydict` looks like what is printed bellow:

```py
#print(mydict)
{('StopPoint:59:3786294', 'StopPoint:59:3730342'): {'time_tc': 120.0},
 ('StopPoint:59:3730342', 'StopPoint:59:4255013'): {'time_tc': 60.0},
 ('StopPoint:59:4255013', 'StopPoint:59:3786297'): {'time_tc': 120.0},
 ('StopPoint:59:3786297', 'StopPoint:59:3786298'): {'time_tc': 180.0},
 ('StopPoint:59:3786298', 'StopPoint:59:3786299'): {'time_tc': 60.0}, ...}

#len(mydict) = 233116
```

I noticed that I was missing almost 100 000 edges after using `G.add_edges_from(mydict)` (`len(G.edges)` = 123976). It is also rather obvious when I draw `G` since many nodes are not linked together with edges. Bellow is what `G.edges` looks like:

```py
#print(G.edges)
{('StopPoint:93:1184', 'StopPoint:93:1260'): {'time_tc': 180.0},
 ('StopPoint:93:1184', 'StopPoint:55:79'): {'time_map': 126},
 ('StopPoint:93:1184', 'StopPoint:55:80'): {'time_map': 126},
 ('StopPoint:93:1184', 'StopPoint:8711610:800:P'): {'time_map': 336},
 ('StopPoint:93:1184', 'StopPoint:93:1183'): {'time_map': 252}}, ...}

#len(G.edges) = 123976
```

There shouldn't be any duplicates in `mydict` so I don't understand why the totality of the edges is not added to the graph. Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Are you using a Graph or DiGraph? If you're building a Graph and your dict contains both (x,y) and (y,x) then one of them will be ignored!

Comment: I am building a graph with ```G = nx.Graph()``` and then added nodes and nodes attributes, which seems to be working fine. I juste get troubles with the edges.

Comment: What is the result of `len(set(frozenset(k) for k in mydict)) == len(mydict)`? You need to check if two keys of `mydict` do refers to the same nodes

Comment: ```len(set(frozenset(k) for k in mydict)) == len(mydict)``` returns a ```False```. So from what I understand there are indeed some repetition of keys. I find it strange as I built ```mydict``` by making sure that only one set of ```(x,y)``` keys is kept so there shouldn't be ```(y,x)``` keys in it. Problem is the ```dict``` is too big for me to check that manually.

Comment: Well, extract all the doubles with python. `set(frozenset(k) for k in mydict if (k[1], k[0]) in mydict)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that your `mydict` variable contains both `(x,y)` and `(y,x)`. If you build a `networkx.Graph` (instead of a `networkx.DiGraph`) then `(x,y)` is considered to be the same of `(y,x)`. Example:

```
import networkx as nx
mydict = {(3,4): 5, (4,3): 6, (1,2): 6}
g = nx.Graph()
di_g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from(mydict)
di_g.add_edges_from(mydict)
print(g.edges) # [(3, 4), (1, 2)]
print(di_g.edges) # [(3, 4), (4, 3), (1, 2)]
```

You can either build a `DiGraph` or remove doubles from `mydict` (this really depends on your specific needs). To extract all the doubles from `mydict` simply do this:

`doubles = set(frozenset(k) for k in mydict if (k[1], k[0]) in mydict)`